# Expose internal storage directory with DocumentsProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-storage

I'm making an app that needs to expose a specific directory `public` in the private storage directory (`/data/data/com.luihum.myapp/files`).

I've looked into the `/sdcard/Android/data` directory, but it doesn't fulfill my needs. Files should be deletable, but not editable or creatable.

I've already got `queryRoots` set up; my app appears in the SAF interface. My question is: how do I implement `queryDocument` and the other functions to expose my private data directory, like Termux does?

---

Update: I've got it to show "No files" instead of "Couldn't load content", I also added a log instruction to the `includeFile` function, and it seems like the files are being included, but they don't show up in the UI. I'm still trying to understand why, any tips?

---

Update 2: While messing with git, I somehow made it kind of work without even touching it. It shows the directories, but not their content. Any tips?

Comment: "I'm making an app that needs to expose a specific directory public in the private storage directory" -- are you sure that this is what you want? This is a rather unusual step for an app to take. "Files should be deletable, but not editable or creatable" -- that is even less usual. Bear in mind that what you are proposing will make your app's files visible in every other app that uses SAF, and the user may not understand that they cannot edit your app's files.

Comment: The files I want to store are binary files, for which there are other tools . I do understand that DocumentsProvider will make it accessible to any SAF app, and also some other considerations related to the way my app works. Deletion is implemented because the user might want to remove a directory, but keep the others, without "Clear data" (the files may be pretty big). Individual files in the same directory depend on each other, but not on files of other directories. I've carefully weighed the pros and cons of each option and chose SAF.

Comment: Do not understand your problem. If you can expose a directory then you can expose a private directory too. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I'm asking how to implement the functions in such a way that a subdirectory in my private directory is exposed. I've tried looking into Termux's code, but it's in Java and my app is in Kotlin, and the Android documentation doesn't cover this.